# Is it possible to change position of 's4-ribbonrow' (browse, page, publish) top bar in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm using design manager to create a master page in SharePoint Online. There is a requirement that i want to move the position of 'Browse, page and publish' bar to some other position. 
[image]

Can we do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to move the “Browse, page and publish”. Use F12 to check the attributes of these elements.

For example:

```
<style>
.ms-cui-tts{
margin: 25px 50px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and is that recommended ?

Comment: Microsoft is not recommended to edit the database directly. It supports to customize the page using code to achieve custom requirements.